# Django Form Select From another model without Foreign Key

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I want to make th_wali get value from another mode.
In User_Admin model there is no 'th_wali'

```
class InsertUser(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta():
        model = User_Admin
        fields = '__all__'

        labels ={
            'username': 'Username',
            'password': 'Password',
            'role' : 'Role',
            'th_wali' : 'Tahun Wali',
        }

        widgets = {
            'username':forms.TextInput(
                attrs={
                    'class':'form-control',
                    'placeholder':'username',
                    'required' : True,
                    'minlength' : 8,
                    }
                ),
            'th_wali':forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Mhs_SI.objects.values('th_masuk').distinct()),
        }
```

I call in template like this, but doesn't show up

```
 <div class="form-group row">
                        <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 ">{{formUser.th_wali.label_tag}}</label>
                        <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-9 ">
                          {{formUser.th_wali}}
                        </div>
                      </div>
```

Comment: [ModelChoiceField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/forms/fields/#django.forms.ModelChoiceField) is a field , not a widget. Like the answer below, you can define the field inside the `InsertUser` form

Answer (score 0):

You can extend the Django `ModelForm` with extra fields.

```
class InsertUser(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta():
        model = User_Admin
        fields = ('username', 'password', 'role', )

        labels ={
            'username': 'Username',
            'password': 'Password',
            'role' : 'Role',
        }

        widgets = {
            'username':forms.TextInput(
                attrs={
                    'class':'form-control',
                    'placeholder':'username',
                    'required' : True,
                    'minlength' : 8,
                    }
                ),
              }
```

Now you can extend this `ModelForm` with your extra field `th_wali` by extending `InsertUser`

```
class ThUser(InsertUser):
    th_wali = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Mhs_SI.objects.values('th_masuk').distinct())
    class Meta(InsertUser.Meta):
        fields = InsertUser.Meta.fields + ('th_wali')
```

Now you can access `th_wali` by using `ThUser` form.

```
{{ThUser.th_wali}}
```